Removing Vinyl Tiles and Plywood Floor
I'm removing old vinyl tiles in what was the main dining/kitchen area:

I would like to put down laminate flooring in the dining area(something thin so the transition to the other rooms, which have thin hardwood strips doesn't become too much of a bulge). And ceramic tiles in the kitchen.
What can I do to prep the surface for both flooring types? The glue on the plywood is quite strong and there are wood ship coming off as the tiles get removed.

You haven't explained your goal. How can we provide advice without knowing what you're doing? Please revise to explain that better. For now, stop shredding the subfloor. It's probably not necessary.

I imagine the subfloor is fine as long as you can fill the shredded spots and avoid any issues with what flooring you are going to put on top.  It still feels structurally solid, correct?  The type of flooring that is going to go down is a big factor in this IMO.

True. The best answer for what you need to do depends on what the finished floor is going to be.  Depending on that answer, you may have not needed to remove the old tiles in the first place.

I have revised my question, hopefully it's clearer.
